# Fast integration of ElementMeshInterpolation[]-functions

Tags: performance-tuning, finite-element-method, interpolation, mesh

In this simplified example I consider a small FEM-mesh

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
poly = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {3/2, 0}, {3/2, 1}, {1 , 1}, {1, 1/2}, {0,1/2}}]
mesh = ToElementMesh[poly, MaxCellMeasure -> 1/5,"MeshElementType" -> "TriangleElement","MeshOrder" -> 1]
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

For this mesh, I define, using `ElementMeshInterpolation[]`, some basisfunctions `φ`

```
p = mesh ["Coordinates"] 
φ = Map[ElementMeshInterpolation[mesh, #] &,IdentityMatrix[Length[p ]]];
```

Trying to integrate products (matrix) of these functions

```
φφ =Outer[Times, Map[#[x, y] &, φ ], Map[#[x, y] &, φ ]];
M = NIntegrate[φφ, Element[{x, y}, mesh]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*~6 seconds *)
```

I notice a large evaluation time.

My question:
How is it possible to speed up integration of expressions formed by `ElementMeshInterpolation[]`-functions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
$Version

"13.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"
```

Many thanks to @Ulrich Neumann for the comments.

Here we provide three alternatives:

1. Options in [`NIntegrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html)
2. Changing the [`InterpolationOrder`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolationOrder.html)
3. Chaning the [`MaxCellMeasure`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxCellMeasure.html)

In each case we provide timings and comparisons of the numerical integration.

---

### **Final version:**

---

- ***Performing the code of the OP for comparison***

We have

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
poly = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {3/2, 0}, {3/2, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1/2}, {0, 
     1/2}}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[poly, MaxCellMeasure -> 1/5, 
   "MeshElementType" -> "TriangleElement", "MeshOrder" -> 1];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

> [image: mesh1]

```
p = mesh["Coordinates"];
φ = 
  Map[ElementMeshInterpolation[mesh, #] &, 
   IdentityMatrix[Length[p]]];
φφ = 
  Outer[Times, Map[#[x, y] &, φ], 
   Map[#[x, y] &, φ]];
```

Ιntegrating

```
MOP = NIntegrate[φφ, 
    Element[{x, y}, mesh]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.14101, Null}

---

- ***A suggestion at the level of `NIntegrate`***

With the mesh of the OP untouched

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
poly = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {3/2, 0}, {3/2, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1/2}, {0, 
     1/2}}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[poly, MaxCellMeasure -> 1/5, 
   "MeshElementType" -> "TriangleElement", "MeshOrder" -> 1];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

the following

```
p = mesh["Coordinates"]
φ = 
  Map[ElementMeshInterpolation[mesh, #] &, 
   IdentityMatrix[Length[p]]];
φφ = 
  Outer[Times, Map[#[x, y] &, φ], 
   Map[#[x, y] &, φ]];
M1 = NIntegrate[φφ, Element[{x, y}, mesh], 
    Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MeshElementType" -> TetrahedronElement, 
        "MaxCellMeasure" -> 1/5}}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

returns

> `{0.542303, Null}`

- Comparing the numerical results

A simple comparison

```
MOP - M1 // Chop[#, 7 10^-3] &
```

> [image: compare1]

---

- ***A suggestion at the level of `ElementMeshInterpolation`***

With the mesh of the OP untouched

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
poly = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {3/2, 0}, {3/2, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1/2}, {0, 
     1/2}}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[poly, MaxCellMeasure -> 1/5, 
   "MeshElementType" -> "TriangleElement", "MeshOrder" -> 1];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

we do

```
p = mesh["Coordinates"]
φ = 
  Map[ElementMeshInterpolation[mesh, #, InterpolationOrder -> 1] &, 
   IdentityMatrix[Length[p]]];
φφ = 
  Outer[Times, Map[#[x, y] &, φ], 
   Map[#[x, y] &, \[CurlyPhi]]];
M2 = NIntegrate[φφ, 
    Element[{x, y}, mesh]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

to get

> `{2.13627, Null}`

which is not a huge improvement.

- Comparing the numerical results

As before

```
MOP - M2
```

> [image: compare2]

---

- ***A suggestion at the level of `MaxCellMeasure`***

We begin with:

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
poly = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {3/2, 0}, {3/2, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1/2}, {0, 
     1/2}}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[poly, MaxCellMeasure -> 1/4, 
   "MeshElementType" -> "TriangleElement", "MeshOrder" -> 1];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

> [image: mesh2]

and proceed as before

```
p = mesh["Coordinates"]
φ = 
  Map[ElementMeshInterpolation[mesh, #] &, IdentityMatrix[Length[p]]];

φφ = 
  Outer[Times, Map[#[x, y] &, φ], 
   Map[#[x, y] &, φ]];
M3 = NIntegrate[φφ, 
    Element[{x, y}, mesh]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{1.71267, Null}`

- Comparing the numerical results

As before

```
MOP[[All ;; -2, All ;; -2]] - M3 // Chop[#, 10^-3] &
```

> [image: compare3]

---

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Evaluation of your code gives `step1: 5.84s (9points)` and `step2: 4.72s (8points)`. Roughly spoken the speedup depends, not surprising,  on the number of points.  Still I'm looking for a speedup which is comparable to FEM realization in Mathematica

Comment: @UlrichNeumann thanks for taking the time to check. I am a bit confused that the first integration gives roughly `6s`, because I copied exactly what you wrote in the OP. And it is evident that I misunderstood your needs, sorry about that.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann sorry for the double-comment, but I forgot to say that if there are no follow-ups here, I feel I should delete my response as it is not well-suited. So just let me know if you have additional comments. Thanks :-)

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I checked your and my code and corrected my answer  to 6s evaluation time.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Many thanks for letting me know. Ok, so can I proceed and delete this approach since it doesn't offer much? Do you have any more comments?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann sorry to bother you again, but if you find some time could you have a look again? Edit 1 suggests two new ways and their timings -not sure if they match what you had in mind. Edit 2 contains a comparison of the `NIntegrate` results

Comment: Thank you for your helpful suggestions. I didn't know NIntegrate-Method-FiniteElement, seems to factor 10 faster!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann thanks for your time. Indeed this seems to be the case. And of course you can consider combinations that are well-suited for your particular needs. I checked as much as I could as you can see, but I suggest running some extra diagnostics :-)